A sensor's idle voltage is 1.1 V, and its triggered output voltage is 5 V. How can I condition the signal to be <0.2 V idle and ~2.5 V triggered?
I'm triggering a high speed camera with an analog chronometer tower that when un-triggered puts out 1.1 V. When an object passes through the tower, it briefly spikes to 5 V. I'm using an old camera that receives a trigger at anything between 0.2 V and a maximum of 5 V.
I don't think that 5 V would hurt it, but I really need to make the idle voltage less than 0.2 V. My knowledge of oscilloscope impedance is fuzzy, but I think I need to use a device with high impedance, otherwise the chronometer signals would be too small. The scope is currently configured for 1 MOhm impedance, and when I set the scope to 50 ohms, a BNC-teed multimeter doesn't see 5 V during trigger.

Is this something that I should use a breadboard and a transistor for? Would that be fast enough for a high speed application? Any other advice is welcome.

What does "high speed" mean? How quickly do you need this circuit to respond? Also, what does oscilloscope impedance have to do with the problem? A diagram showing how the sensor, camera, and oscilloscope are connected to each other might make your problem more clear.

"High speed" means that I will be taking about 100,000 images per second of a little ball bearing moving through a chronometer. When the oscilloscope impedance is set to 50 ohms, the trigger signal doesn't get above 1 V because the low scope impedance is effectively shorting our sensors. I've added a diagram to the question.

Use a comparator with an open-collector output. Then the low output voltage will be quite low (below 0.2 V) and the high output voltage will be whatever you make it using an external pull-up resistor.
To achieve really "high speed" (say, less than 1 us response time) you'll have to be careful about the value of the pull-up resistor relative to the load capacitance.
Edit to add:
After seeing your clarifications, another option here is to use a CMOS digital buffer/driver with TTL-compatible inputs, for example 74AHCT1G125. The TTL-compatible inputs ensure it won't see any voltage below 0.8 V as logic high. The designation as a "buffer/driver" ensures it is able to produce sufficient output current to drive a significant length of coax (but you should still keep your scope set to 1 MOhm input).
If you need a part in a DIP package for ease of prototyping, you could use 74HCT125, but this is an 4-channel chip. You'll want to connect the inputs of the 3 unused channels to valid logic levels to avoid chattering.

What does the "open-collector" output mean with regards to a comparator circuit? I'm only familiar with collectors on transistors, not op-amps. Should I use a transistor on the output of an op-amp?

Open collector means that the output is the more-or-less bare collector of the "final" transistor in the device, as opposed to a push-pull or similar setup. This means that the output is pulled down to ground (-ish, you still have the collector-emitter saturation voltage of a few hundred mV), but allowed to float when the output is "off". Compared to a push-pull setup where the output is actively driven to either of the device's supply rails, this gives flexibility in output voltage range (not limited by the supply, possibly even exceeding it) at the expense of output impedance.

@JakeNixon, RE "Should I use a transistor on the output of an op-amp?", No, you should use a comparator (not an op-amp) with an open-collector output. If you start looking at comparator datasheets, this is a very commonly available feature.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Seeing as you only need to pass occasionbal pulses, a charge pump like this will probably work for you without introducing significant delay.  and given that you're usijg a ballistic chronograph I'm guessing delay is the enemy.
